# Invoke a java application remotely using RabbitMQ

Tags: java, multithreading, rabbitmq

I have a java based simulation model that is proposed to be deployed on a remote server. The simulation model will be executed via a message from a web application and I am using RabbitMQ as the intermediary between the web application and my simulation model. I want to be able to start my simulation when the web application sends a 'start' message to RabbitMQ. What is a good architecture to accomplish this? I am thinking of running a daemon that has a pool of worker threads listening on a specific queue. When a new 'start' message comes in, the daemon will hand over the task of running the simulation to a thread from the pool.
Is this the correct way to approach this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Have you read https://www.rabbitmq.com/getstarted.html getting started from RabbitMQ? or one of the tutorials? They are good.

The describe different kinds of queues with example code like [tutorial-1](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-one-java.html)

Comment: What do you mean by "used to be"?

Comment: Because it has been a long time since I used it, but still looks good